# How to model user behavior with a time series of discrete locations in continuous time?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, geostatistics, sequential-pattern-mining

I have a dataset that contains the sequential locations a user has visited, with start and end times. A small sample:

```
id, starttime, endtime, location
1, 29/06/2023 07:00, 29/06/2023 07:33, A
2, 29/06/2023 07:45, 29/06/2023 09:50, B
3, 29/06/2023 10:00, 29/06/2023 17:02, A
4, 29/06/2023 17:30, 29/06/2023 19:33, C
5, 29/06/2023 19:40, 30/06/2023 08:40, A
6, 29/06/2023 08:44, 29/06/2023 12:50, B
```

where A=home, B=work, C=gym

The dataset contains around 1000 records and ten different locations. I want to extract a behavior pattern that best captures the user's movements, so that I can 1) understand the user's behavior and 2) predict their location. I see two options:

1. Markov chain models. The states are the locations. Then I can calculate the transition matrix and predict what the next location might be, given the current location. However, I'm not sure if this works out with the continuous time aspect of my dataset. Also, I don't know if this will allow me to predict the user's location more steps into the future. E.g., predict its location next week Wednesday at 10am.
2. More advanced models such as RNNs or LSTMs. With these I can make more temporal features (such as day of the week, hour of the day) so that I can capture a more advanced pattern.

I am looking for validation on my thoughts above, or other suggestions on how to extract user behavior patterns from this dataset. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on the data sample, the user id's are unique and there can be no sequential pattern to model as each user has only one location. Should the sample be updated?

Comment: @MikeHunter the sample is data from one person. So, each person has +- 1000 records with their location history.

Comment: Because it would be (much) simpler if the transitions were independent of the times, consider exploring that relationship in the data.  If that assumption looks supportable, then you don't have to consider the times to predict the sequence of future locations. Otherwise, your exploration is likely to suggest ways in which you might need to adopt more complex models.  You have enough data to regress the transition counts on a single covariate such as time of day or elapsed time since the last transition.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your reply. I'm afraid that the transitions are dependent of the time, i.e., some users go to the gym at 8am on Mondays and Tuesdays (and after that they go to work), but at 4pm on Wednesdays (after work). Could you elaborate on your last sentence, "You have enough data to regress the transition counts on a single covariate such as time of day or elapsed time since the last transition"? And do you happen to know more complex models that I might use for this task?

Comment: Given the intraday seasonality, regressing the transition counts on a single covariate, time of day, would be virtually completely uninformative as that single parameter would be a test of linearity. A better solution would be to treat time as a discrete or categorical variate using an ANOVA-type factor or dummy variables, which would condition or control for intraday seasonality across users.

Comment: @Mike What you propose is impossible to carry out with any reasonable precision using just 1000 observations because there are $10(10-1-1)=80$ independent transition probabilities to estimate.  If what you're trying to suggest is that it's important to select one (*perhaps* two) suitable covariates well, then yes: that's crucial.  If that cannot be done, then the two directions to consider are (1) collecting more data and/or (2) simplifying the model by aggregating groups of locations.

Comment: @huber You are assuming a markov-type transition model, are you not? Obviously, that is not the only method available to the OP. Simpler, linear models would be the place to start.

Comment: Sander, I'm as guilty as the next guy in wanting to jump to the coolest, most sophisticated models. In your case, that would prolly be a *hidden markov chain* approach. There's plenty of papers on that method out there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model That said, it's wildly erroneous for someone to claim that it is *impossible* to fit such models. The 21st c has seen a tsunami of algorithmic workarounds to parametrizing such things, both bayesian and frequentist, beginning with the bootstrap and jackknife routines and their cognates.

Comment: @MikeHunter thanks, I appreciate your effort in helping me. Actually I've already made a transition matrix and a simple markov chain, just to see what it would result in. My knowledge of these models is, however, very limited. If you don't mind, could you explain to me how the "hidden" part relates to my original post? As in, what exactly represents the hidden states and what the observations?

Comment: Ok, so you have a learning curve which suggests reading up on references cited in the link. *Hidden* refers to a latent structure in the transitions, something which is up to the analyst to specify. I keep thinking of John Tukey, arguably the 20th c's greatest statistician, wrt your query. Tukey was many things-a brilliant theoretician as well as an *in the trenches* practitioner. His insights wrt exploratory analyses are highly relevant. You've got a start on them but could do more in terms of understanding dependence structures prior to model specification.

Comment: @MikeHunter fair point, I'll start working on my understanding of these principles. Thanks for helping me out, have a good one.

Comment: Simple linear models are always a good baseline against which to measure change and (hopefully) improvement as models become more complex and sophisticated. For example, using lags of the DV is one index of the inertia in the hidden structure you want to understand.